# Using html file as template for component in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have following app structure

```
app
   home
       home.html
       home.ts
       home.sass
   app.component.ts
index.html
```

Essentially I want to divide my pages into separate folders that have style, .ts and .html files related to them

however at the moment loading a template like this

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'admin-app',
    template: 'home/home.html'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

literary loads "home/home.html" string as a template where as I want html contents of the home.html file.

Comment: `template` is a string. You are looking for `templateUrl`.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I think that if you want to pass a template, you should use

```
templateUrl: 'home/home.html'
```

That should make an http request and load the html into your component.

Comment: I had an issue with the path too. The path had to be relative to the root folder unless you specified a module id https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html.

Answer (score 9):

You may want to consider using Webpack. In that case, you simply:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-comp',
    template: require('./mycomp.component.html')
})
```

I've found it to be a solid solution thus far since it will actually throw a compile time error if the URL is incorrect.

Comment: This will break if you attempt to optimize the code with the Angular AOT compiler. Sadly, very little works with AOT.